# Ubuntu (14.04.2(Odroid U3)) - Jasper - No handlers could be found for logger "client.vocabcompiler"

Tags: python, ubuntu, odroid

I'm trying to install jasper on an odroid by following https://github.com/jasperproject/jasper-client/issues/20
but for some reason, everytime I enter:

```
python main.py
```

it pops up with this:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "client.vocabcompiler"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
    runpy.run_path(script_path, run_name="__main__")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 240, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, path_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 82, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_fname, mod_loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "../jasper.py", line 16, in <module>
    from client.conversation import Conversation
  File "../client/conversation.py", line 3, in <module>
    from notifier import Notifier
  File "../client/notifier.py", line 4, in <module>
    from modules import Gmail
  File "../client/modules/Gmail.py", line 5, in <module>
    from dateutil import parser
ImportError: No module named dateutil
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the dependencies:

```
pip install -r jasper/client/requirements.txt
```